# Clustering algorithm which is guaranteed to converge to global minimum

Tags: clustering, k-means, convergence

Well known k-means algorithm is not guaranteed to converge to global minimum. It only converges to local minimum.
So my question is, what are the clustering algorithms that are guaranteed to converge globally?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems to address the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577329/why-doesnt-k-means-give-the-global-minima

Comment: As written there, evaluating all possible solutions will find the global optimum, but this is computationally prohibitive for all except the smallest datasets. I think I have seen algorithms that improve on this  a bit speed-wise (don't remember anymore where), but nothing that makes sense for dataset sizes larger than something like 30 or be it 50.

Comment: I will also add here that the question only makes sense referring to a *specific* given objective function, such as the k-means one. Clustering algorithms in general may imply different objective functions or may even be based on principles different from optimisation. Most objective functions used in clustering make it very hard to find global optima, due to the discrete nature of the clustering problem. But then a local optimum of a suitable objective function will normally be more useful than a global optimum of an unsuitable one.

Comment: Thank you @Lewian for your answers. They are helpful and answering my question.